# Using ob_start to bring in a single variable from multiple files after glob

Tags: php, include, glob, ob-start

I don't know any php but I pieced this together from different sources.  Basically I want to use the file name of the files in a directory as the title of a button.  I do not want to include the index or the template.  I also do not want to include any files which have the variable "$open" with a value of "no".

Basically it's a list of jobs I want posted but I don't want to keep having to create and delete individual php files to do so.

```
<?php 
$dir = '../local'; // The directory containing the files. 
$ext = '.php'; // The file extension. 
?> 

<?php foreach (glob($dir . '/*' . $ext) as $file) { ?> 
    <?php
    ob_start();
    include '$file';
    ob_end_clean();

    echo $open;
    ?>

    <?php if ($file != "../local/index.php" && $file != "../local/template.php"  && $open != "no" ) : ?>
        <a class="button" href="<?php echo $siteURL; ?><?php echo "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file, $ext); ?></a>&nbsp;
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what are you asking?

Comment: Well as far as I can tell this should take every file from the local directory with the extension of  '.php' and place it in the variable $file.  I then want any of the files placed in the $file variable to be used as the text on a button that then links to that files page.  I got it to do this BUT I can't get it to exclude any of the files I have the variable $open = 'no' (which I have placed at the top of every file)  I want to be able to use this as a switch to include/exclude files from being included in the files that have a button made for them.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't store information in a PHP file outside of some configuration settings. What you're looking for is a database.

Comment: Currently if any files do not have a variable `$open` then the last iteration will used again and again. Say you have three files, the first having `$open` and the other two not, `$open` will be the value of the first file. You can add `$open = "yes";` to the top of your foreach which will reset it for every file. Ideally you'd want to use a database or some other storage mechanism... as if any of the files you are including contain a `$file` variable, this will be overwritten in the iteration. Basically this technique is a bit vulnerable.

Comment: Ok! thank you! I will look into databases.  Thank you very much!